# Buttons on ionic item-divider

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm developing an app using Ionic 1 and I'm trying to place two buttons on my item-divider. However, the buttons don't float to the right. Here is my code:

```
<div class="item item-divider">
  Mobile Watchlist
  <a href="#" class="watchlist_menu ">
    <i class="icon ion-android-add"></i>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="watchlist_menu">
    <i class="icon ion-android-add"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Here is my scss:

```
    .item-divider{
      .watchlist_menu {
         float: right;
         margin: 5px;
      }
    }
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Also there's a weird line in between the buttons. I'm not sure why.

*UPDATE

Here is what I want:
[image]

Comment: Are you able to provide a mockup or screenshot of what you are trying to achieve please? It will help with providing a more suitable answer. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try deleting your ".item-divider" from the css.

```
.watchlist_menu {
     float: right;
     margin: 5px;
}
```

Is that what you're looking for?